# Python inserting list of alphanumeric strings into database

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-2.7, alphanumeric

I wanted to insert a list of alphanumeric string into a table but this one does not seems to work since the table is built but the data is not inserted

```
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'qwerty123', 'testdb');
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS alphanum")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE alphanum(Name VARCHAR(25))")
    j=64
    test1 = []
    for i in range(0,26):
        j+=1
        test1.append(j)
        test1.append(j+32)

    for i in range(0,52):
        print chr(test1[i])


    for a in range(0,4):
        for b in range(0,52):
            for c in range(0,52):
                result = chr(a+48)+chr(test1[b])+chr(test1[c])
                print result
                for entry in result:
                    cur.execute("INSERT INTO alphanum VALUES(%s)",(result))
```

Here's some example of the result looks like:

```
0AA
0Aa
0AB
0Ab
0AC
0Ac
0AD
0Ad
0AE
0Ae
0AF
0Af
0AG
0Ag
0AH
0Ah
0AI
0Ai
0AJ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must commit the changes using

```
con.commit()
```

otherwise the changes will not be reflected in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about committing:

```
con.commit()
```